# Find groups of 3-element sets that DO not share elements (no overlap whatsoever) in a list

Tags: python, set, overlap

I've found an algorithm that will sort through a list and display each value of the list of sets and find all sets that do not overlap.

Example

```
c = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for a in range(0, len(c)):
    for b in range(o, len(c)):
        if c[a] does not overlap c[b]:
            new_list.append(c[a] and c[b]:
              # example [1,2,3],[4,5,6]
            if c[b] does not overlap all of new_list:
              # example can't use [4,3,2] because 4 is already in one of the sets
               new_list.append([7,9,8])
```

**Intended output**

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

- Please don't worry about [4,3,2],[7,8,9]. I intend to use this for
  loop in a while loop for the other indices later.

### Question

Is there any pre-existing sorting algorithm in python that will do as  I intend?

Comment: Are the values in each sublist unique i.e. not something like `[4, 4, 6]`?

Comment: @Nick Yes, unique no repeating elements.

Comment: @Nick the manual algorithm works. I've been having trouble getting it converted into code.

Comment: Sorting just re-orders a list, which means it *can't* produce a smaller list.  Thus, no *sorting* algorithm will solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your algorithm that uses a set for checking whether values in a list have been seen before:

```
c = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[4,5,6],[9,5,8],[7,8,9]]

new = []
s = set()

for l in c:
    if not any(v in s for v in l):
        new.append(l)
        s.update(l)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish I worded the question better, this has been a tough one for me.

Comment: By the way, I was using this for experimenting on my algorithm for Exact Three Cover. By the way, it's NP-complete!!!. Thank you so much!! (In the UNLIKELY event this works, I will accredit you for the help! $$$) Here's a pastebin-https://pastebin.com/KNqM8BU7

Comment: @TravisWells haven't seen this one - the maths is a bit of a stretch... good luck with it!